# How to Flatten Array of Arrays of the highest order in a simple way?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a matrix of matrices, given in the following code. I want to flatten the array...

```
e1[l_] = Table[{KroneckerDelta[l, m]}, {m, 1, 2}];

σ[l_, m_, k_] = e1[l].Transpose[e1[m]]; 
na = 4;
Sigma[l_, m_] := TensorProduct @@ Table[ σ[l, m, k], {k, 1, na}]
Sigma[1, 1] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I can do this, but if `na` is very large then this method:

```
ArrayFlatten[ArrayFlatten[ArrayFlatten[ArrayFlatten[Sigma[1, 1]]]]] // MatrixForm
```

is not convenient.

Comment: One way: `Nest[ArrayFlatten, Sigma[1, 1], 3]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd use `FixedPoint`:

```
FixedPoint[ ArrayFlatten, Sigma[1, 1]]
```

We have:

```
ArrayFlatten[ ArrayFlatten[ ArrayFlatten[ ArrayFlatten[ Sigma[1, 1]]]]] ==
FixedPoint[ ArrayFlatten, Sigma[1, 1]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

and

```
FixedPoint[ ArrayFlatten, Sigma[1, 1]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another way is

```
Flatten[#,{{1,3,5,7},{2,4,6,8}}]&
```

Or in general

```
Flatten[#, Transpose@Partition[Range@ArrayDepth[#], 2]] &
```

Verification:

```
s = RandomReal[1.0, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}];

ArrayFlatten@ArrayFlatten@ArrayFlatten@ArrayFlatten[s] == 
    Flatten[#, Transpose@Partition[Range@ArrayDepth[#], 2]] &[s]
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Fold` ignoring the second argument:

```
Fold[ArrayFlatten[#1] &, Sigma[1, 1], Range @ 4]
```

Check:

```
ArrayFlatten[ArrayFlatten[ArrayFlatten[ArrayFlatten[Sigma[1, 1]]]]] == 
 Fold[ArrayFlatten[#1] &, Sigma[1, 1], Range[4]]
```

> True