# Improving code for comparing and modifying nested matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, matrix

I have a matrix such as:

```
 tT = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}};
 a = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
 b = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}};
 c = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};
 d = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}};
 e = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
 f = {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
 g = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
 h = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
 i = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
```

That the picture of matrix is same as:

[image]

In the first step, I want to compare elements of tT11 with the elements of tT12, also compare between  elements of tT11 with the elements of tT13. Moreover, compare between elements of tT12 with the elements of tT13. After that tT21 with tT22 and tT23 and so on.

If at least one of the corresponding elements of tT11 and tT12 are simultaneously equal to 1, I want to put a zero instead for all elements in tT12. Also, I want to make the same comparison,  between elements of tT11 with the elements of tT13 with the same condition. (moreover, tT12 and tT13). Also the corresponding element in other rows. I write below line:

```
Do[
If[tT[[r, n, k, q]] == tT[[r, m, k, q]]==1,
    Do[tT[[r, m, x, y]] = 0,{x,1,3},{y,1,3}]],
    {r, 1, 3}, {n, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 3}, {q, 1, 3}, {m, n + 1, 3}]
```

Actually, my desire is to get the result that I bring it below: I am going to generalize this goal to a much larger matrix and this matrix (tT 3*3) is just an example. How can I modify above written process (code) for more efficiency. How can I replace other commands instead of two `Do` loops. My desired result is:
[image]

Thank you so much for your attention.

Comment: By _"If simultaneously, just one of the element of tT11 and tT12 equal to 1 ..."_,do you mean "one and only one" or "at least one"?

Comment: at least one. ok I will correct the sentence.

Comment: @mostafa See a closely related post [How to Flatten Array of Arrays of the highest order in a simple way?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/how-to-flatten-array-of-arrays-of-the-highest-order-in-a-simple-way/34319#34319).

Comment: @mostafa I don't really understand why `T23_33` is equal to `0` in your example. (same goes with `T33_31`)

Comment: What is T23_33?

Comment: @mostafa Well, {3,3} in `T23`.

Comment: Ok. However, there is not any equality between T23_33 and T22_33 and T21_33, but for my goal in the main program(which this is just a part of that), I must put zero for all of elements, Actually, T23_33 will die because T23_12 and T23_21 are equal to corresponded elements in T22

Comment: The conditions to decide whether an element should be null or not are very vague to me, you should provide an explicit example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern matching approach:

```
Clear[replaceWithZero]
replaceWithZero[l_List] := 
  With[{allZero = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}]}, 
   l //. {a___, x_, b___, y_, c___} /; 
      x != allZero && y != allZero && MemberQ[x + y, 2, {2}] :> {a, x, b, allZero, c}];

replaceWithZero /@ tT // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update**: scaling this function up to take matrices of any size:

```
Clear[compareWithin]
compareWithin[mat_List] := Module[{replaceWithZero, innerDimension},
  innerDimension = Take[Dimensions[mat], -2];
  replaceWithZero[l_List] := 
   With[{allZero = ConstantArray[0, innerDimension]}, 
    l //. {a___, x_, b___, y_, c___} /; 
       x != allZero && y != allZero && MemberQ[x + y, 2, {2}] :> {a, x, b, allZero, c}];
  replaceWithZero /@ mat]

With[{mat = RandomInteger[1, {5, 5, 3, 2}]}, 
  MatrixForm /@ {mat, 
    compareWithin[mat] /. 
     x_List /; MatchQ[Flatten@x, {0 ..}] :> 
      Map[Style[#, Red] &, x, {2}]}] // Row
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a no-loops approach to your problem. First, I am using the fact that you only want to compare tT11 with tT12 and tT13, not with any of the matrices on the other rows of the super matrix. So create a function that operates on a single list of matrices, and then `Map` that function onto your matrix of matrices, `tT`.

```
myfun[a : {__?MatrixQ}] /; Length[a] > 1 &&  (SameQ @@ Dimensions /@ a) :=
 With[{len = Length[First[a]], 
   places = Last /@ Subsets[Range[Length[a]], {2}], 
   maxes = Max /@ Plus @@@ Subsets[a, {2}]}, 
  MapIndexed[
   If[Max[Pick[maxes, places, First@#2]] > 1, 
     ConstantArray[0, {len, len}], #1] &, a]]

myfun /@ tT // MatrixForm
```

[image]

The rationale of my approach is that if you want to replace the submatrix depending on whether *any* of its elements is a 1 that matches up with a 1 in the earlier submatrix. In other words, if any of the elements of the element-by-element sum of the two matrices is greater than 1. Since `Max` is `Listable`, you can test whether the `Max` of the sum of the two matrices exceeds 1. If it is, you then need to work out which submatrix to zero out, which can be worked out as the second element of the corresponding `Subset` of a simple range or integers. If the sum of any of the subsets where the second element is the matrix of interest (determined using `Pick`) has a maximum element above 1, then zero out the matrix.

This function should work for any number of matrices in each row of the super matrix, and for any dimension of the submatrices, as long as all the matrices *in each row* have the same dimensions. I don't think the submatrices even need to be square.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Do' works correctly but unfortunately,  '1' is missed in the first of that:

```
Do[
       If[tT[[r, n, k, q]] == tT[[r, m, k, q]]==1,
             Do[tT[[r, m, x, y]] = 0,
             {x,1,3},{y,1,3}]],
{r, 1, 3}, {n, 1, 2}, {k, 1, 3}, {q, 1, 3}, {m, n + 1, 3}]
```

Although, as I know, it is not so optimum code. I wish to eliminate 'Do' in 'Do'.