# Matrix consisting of the matrices

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I need Dirac Matrix in my work. They consists of PauliMatrix and ZeroMatrix, which is:

```
ZeroMatrix:=IdentityMatrix[2]-IdentityMatrix[2]
```

I define Dirac Matrix as:

```
gamma = ({{PauliMatrix[0], ZeroMatrix}, {ZeroMatrix, -PauliMatrix[0]}}) // MatrixForm;
```

I got such result:

[image]

But I need something else: I need a monolithic table, does not consist of individual blocks. How can I get it? (I need something universal, because I need to use it to construct 4 gamma matrices and spinors).

Comment: In fact this is a special case of [How to Flatten Array of Arrays of the highest order in a simple way?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34318/how-to-flatten-array-of-arrays-of-the-highest-order-in-a-simple-way)

Comment: `Array[0 &, {2, 2}]` would be better than `IdentityMatrix - IdentityMatrix` :)

Comment: @Artes Why not vote to close?  Also a duplicate of [(761)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/761) I believe.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've done it, but since I've been one of the most frequent reviewers I expected others to start closing.

Comment: @Artes There is no obligation but as it takes no longer to vote to close than it does to comment why not vote?

Comment: @ Mr. Wizard: where can I find the reference number linked to the Problem? You have used here 761. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayFlatten[]` takes zeroes as a representation of a zero square matrix:

> ```
> gamma = {{PauliMatrix[0], 0}, {0, -PauliMatrix[0]}}
> ArrayFlatten[gamma]
> ```

Which gives
{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}}